# function aggregate in function aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with MySQL and I need to create long command that has to use many aggregate functions. That's my code ...

```
select count(field) from table group by field order by count(field) desc
```

and I need to SUM or AVG this, I don't know yet but it is irrelevant. When I try to do like this :

```
select avg(count(field)) from table group by field order by count(field) desc
```

I get error. Is the way to use many of this functions in one query or maybe slice it?

The error is: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a subquery:

```
select avg(cnt)
from (select count(field) as cnt
      from table
      group by field
     ) t;
```

A simpler method is to just do the calculation directly:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct field)
from table;
```

Comment: you're missing the windowing function version! :d

Comment: using t in the end, is it some of trick that is used to run this query without errors?